# How to add dynamic element to an array with count of number each?

Tags: jquery, each

I have an ajax response with JSON. It will an anchor tags. There will be n number of anchor tag coming, but i need to break the look at certain count like called 12 and add these anchore tags like the count of 3 in the first li, next 3 anchor tag in the second li and so on...
how the can be achieved with jquery each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I created a function which groups the json array into equal length slices, then it is possible to use `$.each()` nested:

http://jsfiddle.net/s2yts/

```
var json = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function array_group_by_num( a, n ){
    var result = [];
    for( var i=0; i < a.length; i += n ){
        result.push( a.slice( i, i+n ));
    }
    return result;
}

var groups = array_group_by_num( json, 3);

$.each( groups, function( groupIndex, group ){
    var $list = $('<ul/>');
    $.each( group, function( itemIndex, item ){
        $list.append( $('<li>'+item+'</li>') );
    });
    $('body').append( $list );
});
​
```